# Basic FORTRAN function error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I am new to Fortran. I am facing a weird problem and I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I have pasted the minimum working code to demonstrate the problem below.

In the code everything works except the `cosine` function call. It is giving wrong results. The most weird thing is the result changes if I uncomment the commented line below (which is in no way related to the returned value).

(As I've read in several SO questions this looks like a results of an invalid memory access, but couldn't figure anything out)

```
program prog
    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(2) ::  vec1 = (/ 3, 4 /)
    double precision, dimension(2) ::  vec2 = (/ 4, 3 /)

    print *, inner_product(2, vec1, vec2)
    print *, norm(2, vec1)
    print *, cosine(2, vec1, vec2)

contains
    double precision function inner_product(N, V1, V2)
      integer, intent(in) :: N
      double precision, dimension(*), intent(in) :: V1
      double precision, dimension(*), intent(in) :: V2
      integer :: i
      do i = 1, N
          inner_product = inner_product + V1(i)*V2(i)
      end do
    end function inner_product

    double precision function norm(N, V)
      integer, intent(in) :: N
      double precision, dimension(*), intent(in) :: V
      norm = sqrt(inner_product(N, V, V))
    end function norm

    double precision function cosine(N, A, B)
      integer, intent(in) :: N
      double precision, dimension(*), intent(in) :: A
      double precision, dimension(*), intent(in) :: B
      double precision :: na

      ! na = norm(N, A)
      cosine = inner_product(N, A, B) / (norm(N, A) * norm(N, B))
    end function cosine
end program prog
```

---

UPDATE:

Running the posted code gives the following result,

```
   24.000000000000000     
   5.0000000000000000     
  0.67882250993908555
```

Running the program after uncommenting the currently commented line gives the following,

```
   24.000000000000000     
   5.0000000000000000     
  0.39191835884530846
```

None of them are true. The expected result is `0.96` (which is given by `24 / (5*5))`.

Comment: What is a wrong result? Which result does it give? Which result would you expect?

Comment: Why do you use your own `inner product` instead of the intrinsic `dot_product`? And your own `norm` instead of intrinsic `norm2`? Also, with assumed shape arrays you can avoid passing `N` explicitly.

Comment: I have updated the question with observed outputs and the expected output. I can't use built-in functions as this is a homework :)

Comment: OK, wouldn't let my students to learn to use assumed size array this way in modern Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that gfortran doesn't detect your error unless optimization is in force:

```
D:\gfortran\clf\uninit>gfortran -O2 uninit.f90 -ouninit

D:\gfortran\clf\uninit>gfortran -Wall uninit.f90 -ouninit
uninit.f90:31:28:

       double precision :: na
                            1
Warning: Unused variable 'na' declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]

D:\gfortran\clf\uninit>gfortran -O2 -Wall uninit.f90 -ouninit
uninit.f90:31:28:

       double precision :: na
                            1
Warning: Unused variable 'na' declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
uninit.f90:17:0:

           inner_product = inner_product + V1(i)*V2(i)

Warning: '__result_inner_product' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wunin
itialized]
```

It's this last error you want to encourage gfortran to detect.

Comment: Whoa, I feel so stupid :(. I was using `inner_product` without initializing it. Thanks.